# How to avoid truncated text due to single quotes and double quotes?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid, in my description column I am displaying the truncated description and made it as hyperlink which will open the dialog to display the full description, for that I am sending the description value as 'cellvalue'.

Since the my description has single quotes and double quotes makes the description truncated and breaks the text and the hyperlink also not working.

Showing error:

> JavaScript critical error at line 478, column 29 in (unknown source location)\n\nSCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant.

Error from dynamic page:

```
function onclick(event)
{
 ShowDescription('TEST DESCRIPTION's
}
```

Description without single and double quotes displaying correctly in the dialog when hyperlink of the text gets clicked.

This my jqgrid code:

```
        {
            name: 'Description', index: 'Description', formatter: function (cellvalue) { 
                return '<a href="#" style="color:#2A83BB; font-weight: 600" onclick ="ShowDescription(' + "'" + cellvalue + "'" + ')">' + cellvalue + '</a>';
            }//cellvalue.substring(0, 15)
        },


 function ShowDescription(cellvalue)
{
if (cellvalue != null && cellvalue != "") {     
    $("<div></div>").html(cellvalue).dialog({
            title: 'Description',
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }}
```